# Lower triangular matrices and identity question

Tags: matrices

If I have $(L^{−1}M)(L^{−1}M)^T=I$ and both L and M and are lower triangular matrices. Does that mean 
L = M ??
If yes please state the property .

Comment: No. Let $L$ be the identity matrix and let $M$ be the diagonal that has ones all the diagonal except for one spot where it has $-1$. Note that diagonal matrices are lower triangular. Then $(L^{-1} M)(L^{-1} M)^T = MM^T = I$, but $L \neq M$.

Answer (score 0):

Suugaku's example is correct, but please note that your condition essentially says that $LL^T = M M^T$.  Since every positive definite matrix has a unique Cholesky decomposition there is a unique matrix $M$ for which $MM^T=LL^T$ for every matrix $LL^T$ and vice versa if $M$ must have positive real diagonal elements.

So the statement would be true if you required the diagonal entries of $M,L$ to be real and positive.

Comment: That is what I am trying to prove is that $LL^T$ is unique for symmetric positive definite. and that is why I asked the question. Yes $LL^T = MM^T$ then is my statement right, and why? Thanks

Comment: It's right if $L$ and $M$ are required to have positive real diagonal elements.

Comment: The only condition is that A is SPD and $A=LL^T$

Comment: No.  Then Suugaku's example works.